# How to get the int value of 1025 from string=(\"1025\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\") using java?

Tags: java

Below are the string values, i need to extract the value of ID, start date end date separatly 
**(\"ID\",\"StartDate\",\"EndDate\")**

1. (\"1025\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1026\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1027\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1028\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1029\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1030\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1031\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1032\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1033\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1034\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1035\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1036\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1037\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1038\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1039\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1040\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1041\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1042\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1043\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1044\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1045\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")
   (\"1046\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")

Comment: Google 'string handling'

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = "(\"1025\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")";

int num = value.substring(value.indexOf('(\"'),value.indexOf('\"'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
String value = "(\"1025\",\"01-08-2016\",\"07-08-2016\")";

value = value.replaceAll("[\\(\\)\"]", ""); //Remove all unnecessary chars
String[] splittedValues = value.split(",");

System.out.println(splittedValues[0]); //1025
System.out.println(splittedValues[1]); //01-08-2016
System.out.println(splittedValues[2]); //07-08-2016
```